How to visually inspect pads on woodwinds
As a band teacher I am frequently asked to check out Flutes, clarinets, and saxophones.  Parents often have instruments given by family members and are hoping to use them again instead of a new instrument rental/purchase. I'm a brass guy and no expert.
Sometimes it's easy.  They bring me a flute they bought on Amazon for $50 or some ancient clarinet that Grandma played 30 years ago.  Obviously this won't do.  But is there a way to know what condition the pads are in from a quick visual inspection?  Say for example it's a decent instrument that's a few years old.  It would be nice to know the difference between "a few pads and just an adjustment" and "total repad, cost exceeds value" without a trip to the shop?
What should I be looking for?

I think it’s a good question and also wondering if a visual inspection is what you really want.
Personally I could see myself doing a pressure test instead. Take off the mouthpiece or head joint, plug up the open end with a swab, apply a fingering that closes all holes and pads and blow gently into where the mouthpiece would go. If anything isn’t sealing right you should be able to hear and/or feel it. The swab will let air through very slowly but silently so any hissing is probably a bad seal.
This probably wouldn’t work on alto, tenor, and bari sax because their bells are too big to plug with a swab. Not sure about bassoon.
Ideally you’d have extra mouthpieces and reeds in your school instrument library so you could actually playtest instruments. For flutes you could sterisol the head joint after a play test.
If you’re not sure how to play around a two octave scale on these instruments then my personal opinion is you should get on that if you want to keep being a band teacher. There’s a great book on woodwind methods by Charles West that could be your main resource for understanding a teaching woodwinds in a band setting. For me basic scales without regard to tone quality or intonation on woodwinds isn’t very hard - maybe oboe is annoying - and no one should judge if you have a fingering chart in front of you for a basic play test.
I just thought you could also enlist the help of your better wind students, especially if you’re teaching secondary school with teens 15+.

AHA!  That's it!  While I'm pretty comfortable executing a 2-octave scale on these (no worries there) I couldn't figure out how to do a pressure test.  They didn't teach that particular skill in college and I never had enough hands to close the bell.  Swab makes perfect sense so thanks for that.

@nuggethead Got that one from my clarinet teacher, although it was recommended to me as a way to make sure I’m not tensing my throat because if you open the register key you should be able to get a specific pitch that is only possible with a relaxed throat. I wish I had a good idea for the saxes though.

I've done much the same thing with a flute, except I used a "vacuum test": suck on the open end of the instrument with the other end against your thigh and all the keys closed, and if you can remove your fingers from the keys and they stay closed, all the pads are good. Clearly playing scales will tell you which keys are bad.

Check for stopper corks. They can be found in different sizes.

A long, thin lamp that can be slid inside the instrument - particularly the sax family, will show up badly sealing pads as light escaping, when in a darkened room, as well as Todd's ideas.
